# JSON-RPC.NET for windows phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, json-rpc

Can someone explain how to use JSON-RPC.net in my application for windows phone. When I add the link on dll in my project, I get an error that the library has not been built for the Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your JSON-RPC.net library wasn't compiled for the version of the .NET Framework that runs on the Windows Phone. If you've got the sources, try to recompile it for the Windows Phone .NET Framework profile. Otherwise, find a compiled version suitable for the Windows Phone .NET runtime.